# Syntax error at FOR LOOP

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have this function. It's not complete and doesn't do anything meaningful yet, but in the process of writing I've been getting this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LOOP"
LINE 26:  END LOOP;
```

Could anyone look at my code and see why?? My for loop syntax looks fine to me.

```
CREATE FUNCTION assignGrades(prob numeric[], school_name text, school_id bigint) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    num_grades integer ARRAY[6];
    found_school school_probs%ROWTYPE;
    num_students simulated_records%ROWTYPE;
    num_students_int bigint;
    random_record simulated_records%ROWTYPE;


BEGIN
    SELECT INTO found_school * FROM school_probs WHERE school_code = school_id;--select the prob dist
    SELECT INTO num_students * FROM simulated_records WHERE school = school_name;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num_students_int FROM simulated_records WHERE school = school_name;
    num_grades[1] = num_students_int*found_school.probs[1];
    num_grades[2] = num_students_int*found_school.probs[1];
    num_grades[3] = num_students_int*found_school.probs[1];
    num_grades[4] = num_students_int*found_school.probs[1];
    num_grades[5] = num_students_int*found_school.probs[1];
    num_grades[6] = num_students_int*found_school.probs[1];

    FOR i IN 1..num_grades[1] LOOP

        SELECT INTO random_record * FROM simulated_records WHERE school = school_name ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
        IF random_record.grade IS NULL THEN
            random_record.grade = 'A';
    END LOOP;--syntax error here


END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have missed the

```
END IF;
```

part.